# Does the chain rule apply in inverse function derivatives?

Tags: derivatives

My problem is finding the derivative of $y=\arctan (3x)$. Would it be

$$y'= \dfrac{1}{1+(3x)^2}$$

or

$$y'= \dfrac{1}{1+(3x)^2}\times 3$$

Comment: ok thank you for the advice!

Comment: Who voted to close as "primarily opinion-based"?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm...Second one because

> $$y=f(g(x))$$
>   $$y'=f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$$

Now put $f(x)=\arctan(x)$
and $g(x)=3x$
$$y=\arctan(g(x))$$

$$y'=\frac{1}{1+(g(x))^2}\cdot g'(x)=\frac{3}{1+(3x)^2}$$

> This was added as a response to OP's comment

[$$\frac{d}{dx}\arcsin(e^{2x})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(e^{2x})^2}}\cdot e^{2x}\cdot2=\frac{2e^{2x}}{\sqrt{1-e^{4x}}} $$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=differentiate%20arcsin(e%5E(2x)))

Comment: yes it does! thank you!

Comment: so would the derivative of arcsin(e^2x) be the derivative of arcsin * e^2x * 2?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the chain rule applies to derivatives of inverse trigonometric functions.

$$y'= \dfrac{1}{1+(3x)^2}\times 3$$